# Can't update css animation-duration in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, webix

This is my CSS

```css
.marquee {
 color: red;
 margin: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 white-space: nowrap;
 animation-name: marquee;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-duration: 10s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee{
 0%{
   transform: translate(10%, 0);
 }

100%{
   transform: translate(-100%, 0);
 }
```

This is my Javascript function to update CSS animation duration

```js
calcSpeed: function (speed) {
  var spnSelect = document.querySelectorAll('.marquee');

  var i=0;
  for(i=0; i< spnSelect.length; i++) {
    var spnLen = spnSelect[i].offsetWidth;
    var timeTaken = spnLen / speed;
    spnSelect[i].style.animationDuration = timeTaken +'s';
  }
}
```

I don't know why I can't update the css animation duration.
I deleted animation-duration and run the code.
The text became stopped.
I don't know what to do.
Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you've got the timeTaken nominator and denominator switched

```
    var i=0;
    for(i=0; i< spnSelect.length; i++){
     var spnLen = spnSelect[i].offsetWidth;
//    var timeTaken = spnLen / speed;
    var timeTaken = speed / spnLen; // this will spread speed over each spnSelect element
    spnSelect[i].style.animationDuration = timeTaken +'s';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for the answer.  But I still can't update the css duration!

Answer (score 0):

was it necessary? The problem was the missing parenthesis `}`. And you haven't called the function - `text_run(1000);`. You can also adjust the text speed in the function call - `1000`.

```js
function text_run(speed) {
  var spnSelect = document.querySelectorAll('.marquee');

var i=0;
for(i=0; i< spnSelect.length; i++){
 var spnLen = spnSelect[i].offsetWidth;
var timeTaken = spnLen / speed;
spnSelect[i].style.animationDuration = timeTaken +'s';
}
}

text_run(1000);
```

```css
.marquee {
 color: red;
 margin: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 white-space: nowrap;
 animation-name: marquee;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-duration: 10s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 width: 100%;
}

@keyframes marquee{
 0%{
   transform: translate(100%, 0);
 }

100%{
   transform: translate(0%, 0);
 }
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  Test text
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for the answer. But still can't update the animation duration! The text is moving with the old value of animation duration.